# GridView pagination performance

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination, performance-measuring

Let's say I have a GridView with 1.000 rows. And I don't want any pagination and have all the rows visible. I can do two things:

Set `AllowPaging="false"` (most logical)

Or

Set `AllowPaging="true"` and with a higher PageSize than the total rows: `PageSize="9999"`

So my question is if there is any significant difference in performance between both options and if so, how do you measure something like that.

Comment: Use datatable https://datatables.net/

Comment: The logic dictates that `AllowPaging="true"` will take a bit more to complete since it is needed to calculate and render the paging options to the grid.But this performance impact will not be significant because the rendering of the 1000 rows is rather heavy. To measure those, counting the total page render time for the .aspx page would give you the numbers. You could do it by adding a Timer in the page of by viewing the time from the dev tools in any browser.

Comment: @VDWWD what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Leopard. I have a site with a lot of GridViews (with 250 rows max). User can define default row numbers to display: all, 10, 25 etc. When user wants all rows I store that value as 1000 and set that as `PageSize` on each grid. That way I don't have to check if rows are `all` or `integer` and enable/disable `AllowPaging`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working for more than 4 years as web developer specifically `asp.net` developer. I have widely used [datatables.net](https://datatables.net). It is very powerful,rich of features and evry easy to use.

If your gridview has `250 rows` max `datatable` can easily digest `250 rows`. I would recommed you to load `250 rows` initially and when user change number of rows you can simply set `option of datatable` to show that many records.

Once your `gridview` has loaded you can apply `datatable` to it.Here is a little example. here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjhxoau9/)

You need to set `'pageLength': 25` property to decide how many records to display. initially set it to `250` after user will change the option no `server side` call will be sent.

And use `'lengthMenu'` option to show number of records to show.

```
$("#tblInfo").dataTable({
            'pageLength': 25,
            'lengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250], [10, 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250]]
        });
```